# cant open linux and is stil showing me this eror

Tags: linux

VM Name: kali-linux-2024.1-virtualbox-i386

Could not open the medium 'C:\kali-linux-2024.1-virtualbox-i386.vdi'.
VD: error VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND opening image file 'C:\kali-linux-2024.1-virtualbox-i386.vdi' (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).
Result Code:
E_FAIL (0X80004005)
Component:
MediumWrap
Interface:
IMedium {ad47ad09-787b-44ab-b343-a082a3f2dfb1}

Comment: Did you get the correct file from here?   https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-virtual-machines

Comment: Also you may be more successful downloading the ISO file and making your own machine in VBOX (Make New Machine)

Comment: Note that you aren't in Linux yet, you're still on the host trying to get a VM to start. Please keep that in mind when applying tags and describing your problem. Can you describe how you set this up, what research you have done, and what you have tried so far?